# How do i make this python login/register program work? (I am new to python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, authentication

**So i am quite new to python** (knew C# before trying to learn python) and i wanted to make an **little login/register program**, i wrote it all, theorically (at least to me) it would work, but it doesn´t, it doesn´t logs indenpendently of that account existing or not...

**How do i make this program work?**

```py
command = ""
username = ""
password = ""

def Register():
    global username
    global password
    username = input("Username: ")
    password = input("Password: ")

    f = open("userinfo.txt", "a")
    f.write("--------------------")
    f.write("\n%s information:\n"%(username))
    f.write("%s \n"%(username))
    f.write("%s \n"%(password))
    f.write("--------------------")

def Login():
    global username
    global password
    f = open("userinfo.txt", "r")
    f.readline()
    f.readline()
    username = f.readline()
    password = f.readline()
    f.readline()
    return username
    return password

def CheckLogin():
    global username
    global password
    global loginusername
    global loginpassword

    if loginusername == username and loginpassword == password:
        print("You´ve logged in, wait for next updates")

    elif loginusername == username and loginpassword != password:
        print("Wrong password")

    elif loginusername != username and loginpassword == password:
        print("Wrong username")

    elif loginusername != username and loginpassword != password:
        print("Wrong login information, restart the program and register to create an account")

    else:
        print("ERROR: Uknown error")


command = input("Would you like to login or register?\n")
if (command == "register"):
    Register()
    print("Done!")

elif (command == "login"):
    print("--------LOGIN--------")
    loginusername = input("Username: ")
    loginpassword = input("Password: ")
    Login()
    CheckLogin()



else:
    print("Invalid command")
    print("Please restart the program and try again")
```

So, do i need to make class related stuff?
like, users being objects?
but how would i save that data?

**Please help me**

Edit: did some minor polishing on the code, fixed an error but now i have other...

Comment: I would recommend passing the variables username and password from function to function.  Typically most people stay away from global variables.  It can make it easier for you to code in a mistake as any function can change the value in the variable rather.

Comment: also note that camel case is usually used for class names, not functions, per the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: What does it change though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
if (loginusername == username , loginpassword == password):
```

This creates a tuple containing two Boolean values and asks whether that tuple is truthy. Since it is not empty, it is.  Therefore this `if` statement's body always executes.

You want:

```
if loginusername == username and loginpassword == password:
```

You make the same error elsewhere.

N.B. you do not need to enclose conditions in a `if` statement in parentheses.